# Filemaker Server Not Installing and Windows Problems

Tags: windows-server-2003-r2

When I tried installing Filemaker Server 8.0 on Windows 2003 Server Standard Edition R2, an error message pop up that states:

MMC has detected an error in a snap-in.  It is recommended that you shut down and restart MMC.

After this message pops up, Filemaker Server freezes.

---

I'm also having problems with openssl and running executable files, but am not sure if the 2 are related.

Error message for openssl states:

Openssl.exe encountered a problem and needed to close.

In one of the computers connected to the network running this same Server 2003 R2, when I tried double-clicking on Dr. Web antivirus to do a scan, nothing happens.  I have done this many times before reinstalling the server, and it never gave trouble before this.

Any help given is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suspect that you have versions of the OpenSSL libraries in some directory in your PATH that are mismatched with the versions that FileMaker Server is looking for.

Look for copies of "libeay32.dll" and "libssl32.dll" in directories in your path (particularly in %SystemRoot%\system32). If you find copies rename them and see how you fare with FileMaker Server. Ultimately, you'll need to find the application that relies on the files you find and relocate the files to the directory where that application is installed.

Comment: Thanks Evan. I will try your method, but my guess is that I will need to re-install the server since there are more problems popping up. I would have used System Restore if this is available but as far as I know, Server 2003 does not have an option for System Restore.